# Azure log analytics windows agent inside windows container

Tags: azure, docker, log-analytics-workspace

Is it possible to setup Azure Log analytics windows agent inside windows container?

I get the below error in eventvwr

> HTTP operation failed with error "The Server service is not started."
> (2114L).  The query will be retried later.  The article KB3126513 has
> additional troubleshooting information for connectivity issues.

Server service does not exist and my research says Windows container does not support Server services.
Is this even supported?

Comment: You answered your own question in your second last line.

Comment: Yes, but if I could reframe my question to "how could I capture logs particularly event/IIS and custom logs"?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot run the log analytics agent inside a Windows container (or any container). In a container based environment you would generally run this agent on the host machine, or as it's own container in the case of Kubernetes.

Comment: For Event viewer, IIS and custom logs (residing inside container), what would be the best approach?

Comment: Your best bet is to ensure that these logs are published to the container log stream, then you can use the Log Analytics agent to collect these